# Checking for null objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, null

I have the following code snippet that defines the property values in my form.

```
function retrieve(){
    setSelectedIndex(document.producerSetForm.GA1,"<%=ssnGA1%>");
    setSelectedIndex(document.producerSetForm.GA2,"<%=ssnGA2%>");
    setSelectedIndex(document.producerSetForm.GA3,"<%=ssnGA3%>");
    setSelectedIndex(document.producerSetForm.GA4,"<%=ssnGA4%>");
    setSelectedIndex(document.producerSetForm.GA5,"<%=ssnGA5%>");
}
```

where these ssnGA1,ssnGA2 etc may or may not be having a value. I need to check whether whether they have a value to do some more processing. I tried

```
var len=<%=ssnGA1.toString().length()%>;
if(len !=0)
```

but it works only if the value is present. else it giving javascript error. Please help. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if your string is not undefined/null first, on example:

```
if ( ssnGA1 && ssnGA1.toString().length ) {
  // do something
}
```

Also, `length` is a property, not a function, [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) for details.

Comment: var str = <%=ssnGA2.toString()%>;
 alert(typeof(str));
I am getting the type as number. hence not able to check string against the length or any other property.

Comment: Try: var str = "<%=ssnGA2.toString()%>"; (I'm guessing ssnGA2.toString() returns a number).

Comment: i tried that and its not working. since its returning number not able perform any check. returning java script error. str is having a number. if ssnGA2 property is not having a value var str = <%=ssnGA2.toString()%> won't work. need some alternative to check that